# curl to Elasticsearch “connection refused” on Vagrantfile

Tags: elasticsearch, vagrant, vagrantfile

I try to start elasticsearch and configure its schema on Vagrantfile.
But, when I put schema json file using curl on Vagrantfile, “connection refused” error happens, though elasticsearch has started successfully.

> > curl -X PUT http://192.168.33.20:9200/test --data-binary @/synced_folder/schema.json

[error message]

> > 0curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.33.20:9200; Connection refused

※After vagrant up has finished, this command is successful. concretely...

> > sudo ssh 192.168.33.20

and

> > curl -X PUT http://192.168.33.20:9200/test --data-binary @/synced_folder/schema.json

It’s no error and schema is configured successfully.

> > {"acknowledged":true}

But, I want to configure schema on "vagrant up" process.
Why does "connection refused" error happen on Vagrantfile?

[Vagrantfile]

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
 config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"
 config.vm.box_url = "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/centos-7.1"
 config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.20"
 config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/synced_folder"
 config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./script.sh"
end
```

[script.sh]

```
#!/bin/sh

#install java
yum -y install java

#install and start elasticsearch
rpm --import https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
cp /synced_folder/elasticsearch.repo /etc/yum.repos.d
yum -y install elasticsearch
sed -i '/# network.host: 192.168.0.1/a\network.host: 192.168.33.20' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
#Japanese morphological analysis plugin
bin/plugin install analysis-kuromoji
service elasticsearch start

#configure index 
curl -X PUT http://192.168.33.20:9200/test --data-binary @/synced_folder/schema.json
```

[/synced_folder/schema.json]

```
{"mappings":{"comment_data":{"properties":{"comment":{"type":"string","store":"yes","index":"analyzed"},"date":{"type":"date","store":"yes"},"vps":{"type":"float","store":"yes"}}}}}
```

Comment: disable firewall if its running (`sudo systemctl disable firewalld`) and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks! I firstly think "firewalld" is the cause and tried it, but it wasn't the cause.

Comment: Could you please check the `telnet 192.168.33.20 9200` response? It sounds like the port is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `telnet 192.168.33.20 9200`. The response console is `Trying 192.168.33.20... Connected to 192.168.33.20. Escape character is '^]'. `.It looks successful.

Answer (score 4):

I could solve this problem.
I found elasticsearch actually start a few seconds later after service started.
So I add a waiting process to a shell script.
Thanks!

```
while true;
do
    echo "waiting Elasticsearch..."
    curl -X -s GET http://192.168.33.20:9200
    if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then
        echo "Elasticsearch started!"
        break
    fi
    sleep 1s
done
```

Comment: Oh... dude... saved me #vagrant #ubuntu-14.04 #bash #shell